# Constructors and Strings

Tags: java

I'm fairly new with Java and I'm having some trouble understanding what I need to do.

Directions are as follows: Provide a class for authoring a simple letter. In the constructor, supply the names of the sender and the recipient:

```
public Letter (String from, String to)
```

Supply a method.

I have a few things if someone could clarify would be a huge help. 
I'm just a little confused on the constructor. If Im not mistaken the constructor is:

```
public Letter (String from, String to)
```

Do I need to do something to it. Change the from or to to names. I have tried setting them as variables but i think that is wrong
something like this `from="Dylan";`

Also, what method would I supply here? I'm just getting started in all this and find it very confusing and just need some clarification.

Comment: If you want feedback about your version of `Letter` so far, you should post a new question.

Comment: Pretty please with sugar on top.

Comment: I have now deleted your `Letter` class. Don't worry, it's still there if you click on the link that says your post was just edited.

Answer (score 2):

Constructors are used to pass data to the initialization process of an object. In this case, the data is a `String`, `from`, and another `String`, `to`. Constructors are actually a special case of methods, they are actually methods that are named `<init>`. So you can use `from` and `to` just as you would use any method parameter.

Most of the time, if you want to do anything useful with the parameters, you would store them in variables. Here's an example:

```
public class Car { // this is not the Letter class on purpose, you should write your own
    private String name;
    private int year;

    public Car(String n, int y) {
        name = n;
        year = y;
    }

    // lots of other methods, which can do anything with name and year
}
```

You could modify this for your `Letter` class.

Answer (score 0):

You can start with something like this:

```
public class Letter {

    private String source;
    private String destination;
    private String content;

    public Letter (String source, String destination){
        this.source = source;
        this.destination = destination;
    }

    public boolean send(){
        //do something and return true or false, wether the letter
        //was successfully sent or not
        return true;
    }

    public void fillContent(String content){
        this.content = content;
    }

}
```

After that, create an object of type Letter that will be send from A to B.

```
Letter letter = new Letter("A", "B");

letter.fillContent("Bienvenido");

boolean status = letter.send();
```

Comment: Hmm, wonder why both answer have received a -1

Comment: no idea :O/ @Vallentin

Comment: I'm the down voter. You shouldn't post the answer to this guy's homework. Only give hints.

Comment: I also downvoted. Same reason as @tbodt

Comment: I don't agree, this piece of code will give the user the opportunity to write more code on top of this, and more importantly, the possibility of test and learn how this works. I believe this is just a helpful hint.

Answer (score -1):

Your Letter class would look something like the following

```
public class Letter{
     private String from, to;

     public Letter(String from, String to){
         this.from = from;
         this.to = to;
     }

    public void someMethod(){//do something}


}
```

You need to declare fields within your class that will take the input from your constructor. This way your class Letter can use the from and to fields in your methods

Comment: You shouldn't provide the answer to the OP's homework. Just give him hints.

Comment: My answer is hardly different than yours.

Comment: Well, what you have there would be a very nice `Letter` class that the OP could just use, without actually learning about constructors.

Comment: My comment underneath the code provided info about what needed to be done. I agree that code should not be handed out freely but it is often nice to see sample code relating to the question instead of a more abstract example.

Comment: if you really want more reputation, delete this answer and look elsewhere.

Comment: That seems unnecessary.

Comment: I am, at this point, abandoning this discussion. Proceeding would not result in any conceivable benefit for me.

Comment: For both of you: There has been [a question on meta](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/76694/downvoting-too-useful-answers-to-homework-questions) about this. If you read all the comments as well you'll see that there are different opinions about this (personally I think simply *not* upvoting can be enough, instead of actually downvoting)